# Cosmos DB convert properties from PascalCase to CamelCase

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, lowercase, camelcasing

Our Cosmos DB data has become a mixture of items, older ones with PascalCase property names and new ones  with CamelCase:

```
    "RowVersionGUID": "5f86bca2-544b-49a3-a158-3f04aebeb802",
    "Results": {
        "Type": "POI",
        "Id": "US/POI/p0/6214706",
        "Score": 99.81322378417969,
        "Dist": 86.74439569019203,
        "Info": "search:ta:840319000246138-US"
    }
```

and new data

```
    "rowVersionGUID": "bf97ad6b-a79f-458e-aacc-3191e726a1c9",
    "results": {
        "type": "POI",
        "id": "g6JpZK84NAAzMjkwMDA0ODk1MjChY6NVU0GhdqdVbmlmaWVk",
        "score": 99.93961783544922,
        "dist": 70.31082467871605,
        "distKM": 0.07028082477871604,
        "info": "search:ta:840229000489420-US"
```

We think the problem arrived in the conversion from NewtonSoft to System.Text.Json, but we are less interested in the post-mortem and more interested in just fixing the old data.  It is Prod data but hasn't gone Live yet, and the system is working fine otherwise.

Any suggestions on how to convert all the old items from PascalCase to CamelCase?  Particularly anything short of writing a program to read items in, convert and write them back.

Comment: There is nothing automatic that can be done, without setting something up specific to read from one set of property names and update those documents to have new property names. You may want to look at ChangeFeed as one option, which is a built-in feature of Cosmos DB, to consume all existing documents.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory is designed for this very operation.  If you needed to move from one CosmosDb instance with settings that can't be changed after creation (to a defferent Db), you would create it's replacement and use Azure Data Factory to migrate the data.

At least you don't have to write the application yourself.

References:

Azure Data Factory Product Page - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/

Copy and transform data in Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API) by using Azure Data Factory
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db